# Eta square and effect size in General Linear Model

Tags: anova, effect-size, univariate, generalized-eta-squared

I have an unbalanced data set that is categorized in 3 different topics. I wanted to see that how these different topics are effecting the data. So I used `Generalized Linear Model` to investigate this issue. For the significant results of `ANOVA` test, I dig more to see how is the effect size. So I managed to calculated the Eta square and then by measuring the value for power of two of the `Eta square` value, we can gain the effect size. My question is that, for example, for a effect size of `20%`, we can say that the value of a particular category are dependent to each other like 20%?